# Why is this code not producing an output?

Tags: c

Im writing a simple program to show the distance/time between two converging trains. I wanted to test the program and return output value through the function float converge, and then apply that to the main function, but it seems that the converge function does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float converge(int x, int y, int z) {
    return x / (y + z);
}

int main(void) {
    int dist, speed1, speed2;
    printf("Enter distance in miles");
    scanf("%d\n", &dist);
    printf("Enter train 1 speed and train 2 speed in mph");
    scanf("%d%d\n", &speed1, &speed2);

    converge(dist, speed1, speed2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show the output you get. Especially explain what output you expect after the second scanf. You now that calling a float-returning function and ignoring the returned value will not produce any output, don't you? I mean you are aware of printf, so you should know.

Comment: Because there are no output statements apart from the prompts. Aside: please remove the `\n` newline from the `scanf` statements.

Comment: Expecting output from non-existing output statements is not a reproducable problem.

Comment: `converge` performs integer arithmetic and converts the result to `float` only for the return value. If you want to compute a fractional number, you should change it to: `double converge(int x, int y, int z) { return (double)x / ((double)y + z); }` or better `double converge(double x, double y, double z) { return x / (y + z); }`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


float converge (float x, float y, float z)
{
  int time=x/(y+z);
  return time;
}

int main ()
{
    float dist, speed1, speed2;
    printf("Enter distance in miles:\t");
    scanf("%f", &dist);
    printf("Enter speed of first train in mph:\t");
    scanf("%f", &speed1);
    printf("Enter speed of second train in mph:\t");
    scanf("%f", &speed2);

    printf("Time between this two trains is %f",converge(dist, speed1, speed2));


}
```

Comment: Curious, why does code use  `float` instead of `double`?

Comment: Do not have specific reason , float was used in the original code by the person asked the question...Them I just go on with float instead of double

Comment: Aside: append `'\n'` to  `"Time between this two trains is %f"` to help insure output occurs before code ends.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this code not producing an output?

It produces no output for the expected output from the result of `converge()` because there is no statement in the provided code, which could cause this output.

You need for example one `printf()` statement after the call to `converge()` in order to print the result of `converge()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float converge (int x, int y, int z)
{
  return x/(y+z);
}

int main (void)
{
  int dist, speed1, speed2;
  float converge_result;

  printf("Enter the distance between the two trains in miles:\n");
  scanf("%d", &dist);
  printf("\n");

  printf("Enter the speed of train 1 and the speed of train 2 in mph:\n");
  scanf("%d %d", &speed1,&speed2);
  printf("\n");


  converge_result = converge(dist, speed1, speed2);

  printf("The time until the two trains encounter each other is:\n %f",converge_result);

  return 0;
}
```

or alternatively:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float converge (int x, int y, int z)
{
  return x/(y+z);
}

int main (void)
{
  int dist, speed1, speed2;


  printf("Enter the distance between the two trains in miles:\n");
  scanf("%d", &dist);
  printf("\n");

  printf("Enter the speed of train 1 and the speed of train 2 in mph:\n");
  scanf("%d %d", &speed1,&speed2);
  printf("\n");

  printf("The time until the two trains encounter each other is: \n%f ",
  converge(dist,speed1,speed2);

  return 0;
}
```

By the way, the calculation of the distance in time seems incorrect or at least incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `converge` performs integer arithmetic and converts the result to `float` only for the return value. If you want to compute a fractional number, you should change it to: `double converge(int x, int y, int z) { return (double)x / ((double)y + z); }` or better use `double` for the input values and the argument types:

  ```
  double converge(double x, double y, double z) { return x / (y + z); }
  ```
- There are trailing newlines in the `scanf()` conversion formats: this will cause `scanf()` to consume any trailing white space typed after the numbers, including any number of newlines typed at the prompts. You will not get the second prompt as long as you enter empty lines. Remove these `\n` from the format strings.
- The result of the computation is not printed.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

double converge(double x, double y, double z) {
    return x / (y + z);
}

int main(void) {
    double dist = 0, speed1 = 0, speed2 = 0;

    printf("Enter distance in miles: ");
    scanf("%lf", &dist);

    printf("Enter train 1 speed and train 2 speeds in mph: ");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &speed1, &speed2);

    if (speed1 + speed2 <= 0)
        printf("No collision\n");
    else
        printf("Time until collision: %f seconds\", 3600 * converge(dist, speed1, speed2));

    return 0;
}
```